# Javascript - inc var +18 each certain value stepper

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

- Hi, fast and simple: simple JS
- this code work 100% - increment +1 each single For step: OK!

  ### - I NEED increment +1 each 3 steps.

  ```
  var x = 0;

  for(var _i = 0; _i < 2000; _i++)
      {
         x++;        // --- OK
         x = x + 18; // --- "each _i=3, _i=6, _i=9, _i=12..." (etc)
      };
  ```

### - how?

- thanks in advance`enter code here`

Comment: you need to increment by one or by 18 every three steps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't modulo work for you here.

```js
var x = 0;
var maxLimit = 20;
for (var _i = 0; _i < maxLimit; _i++) {
  x++; // --- OK
  if (_i % 3 === 0 && _i > 0) {
    x = x + 18; // --- "each _i=3, _i=6, _i=9, _i=12..." (etc)
    console.log('Increment: x + 18...');
    console.log('_i = ', _i);
    console.log('x = ', x);
  }
}
```

Comment: (I was already creating a complex algorithm between divisions, remains and check various, wasted time...) --- thanks for time you've dedicated me. that's the right way, within reminder = 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
var x = 0;
for(var _i = 0; _i < 2000; _i++) {
  x++;
  if (_i % 3 === 0) x += 18;
}
```

Comment: Oh yes the reminder == 0! - modulo way. precious answer. thank you for the time you dedicated me. (I was already creating a complex algorithm between divisions, remains and check various, wasted time...)

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = 0;
for(var _i = 0; _i < 2000; _i++)
{
   x++; // really?
   if (_i % 3 === 0) { // modulo does it, but compare for type too (===) to do it correctly from beginning on
       x += 18;
   }
};
```

Comment: (I was already creating a complex algorithm between divisions, remains and check various, wasted time...) --- thanks for time you've dedicated me. that's the right way, within reminder = 0.